# How can convert given POSIXct date format to dd-mm-yyyy?

Tags: r

[image]

Original dates have been given in POSIXct format. I need to convert it to dd-mm-yyyy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think gsub solves your problem.

df$date is your column in which date is inside.

df$date <- gsub("/", "-", as.character(df$date))

Comment: the given dates in csv sheet have been given in m/d/y.....I want to change it to d/m/y. The date column is of POSIXct type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input dates are in dd/mm/yy format:

```r
as.POSIXct('02/11/18', format = '%d/%m/%y') |> format('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: the given dates in csv sheet have been given in m/d/y.....I want to change it to d/m/y. The date column is of POSIXct type.

Comment: If your input data is already POSIXct all you have to do is: `format(dates_vector, '%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: thanks! and how do I do that for a date column in a dataframe? Sorry to trouble you with asking for the code.

Comment: Same basic idea... let's say your data.frame `df` has columm `dates` containing data of type POSIXct then you would do: `format(df$dates, '%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: Done!! so the desired date format appears in the console. But how do make see the changes when in View(df) so I can export back to Excel?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - if you want to make the format change permanent, assign the new format to your df. e,g  
my_df$dates <- c("02/11/18", "02/11/18", "02/11/18")
newFormatDates <- as.Date(my_df$dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
my_df$dates <- format(newFormatDates, "%d-%m-%Y")